# Android Studio representing anonymous inner class

Tags: android, android-studio

I created a brand new Android application in Android Studio 0.3.6 with a LoginActivity.java that was created for me. When I view the `onCreate` function I see the following code:

[image]

But when I click on the highlighted `(view)-> {` code Android Studio displays what I would have expected to see:

```
findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        attemptLogin();
    }
});
```

My questions

1. What is this called?
2. Why does Android Studio do this?
3. Is this something I can take advantage of since it is much less typing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's doing code folding similar to *Java 8* *lambda expressions* (see the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)) even if your code isn't actually compiled with Java 8; it's just a convenience for a more compact display.

If you want to use them yourself, you can use *Android Studio* with *Java 1.7* as a compile language, but you'll need to be using build tools v19 or later, and if you use certain language features, it will only run on phones with Kit Kat or later. *Lambda functions* won't get you into trouble, though.

Comment: actually this is java 8 feature

Comment: Specifically, there is a setting under Code folding called "Closures (anonymous classes implementing one method)" that you may enable or disable. You can also manually fold/unfold using ctrl alt -/+, respectively. Unfortunately I don't know of any way where you actually type the shorthand version and AS autogenerates the full code, only the opposite.