# how to collapse listener in android studio

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

In android studio you can collapse/expand code snippets by toggling +/- in editor(Code/Folding). But when I have a listener, it doesn't collapse whole code but just part of it. How can I hide whole listener? For example when I want to collapse below code:

```
View.OnClickListener ctgClick = new View.OnClickListener(){ //hide from here
        public void onClick(View v){
            int tag =(Integer) v.getTag();
            Intent intent= new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("ctg", tag);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
        }
    };//to here
```

it just hides part of code like this:

```
View.OnClickListener ctgClick = (v) -> {
            int tag =(Integer) v.getTag();
            Intent intent= new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("ctg", tag);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 7):

**@mayan anger** was partly right. Just go to

```
File->Settings->Editor->General->Code Folding
```

And uncheck `Closures`, now it's working the way I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio this 'collapse' called `Folding`.

You can try setting your own Custom `Folding`, 
Just go to File->Setting->General->Code Folding.
And make share this one choose :
[this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBQP4.png)

Comment: I know it's called Folding, i mentioned it in my question. I checked inside settings and "Closures" is checked.

Comment: i see, you are right, android studio not collapse entire anonymus class that have only one method.      but you can still try change your java display 6 to java 8  as can see hare : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20177359/android-studio-representing-anonymous-inner-class